# How to debug a SQL script containing INSERT statements with failing subqueries?

Tags: linux, mysql, database, sql, database-administration

I have three tables in my database: `tbl_object`, `tbl_tag` adn `tbl_object_tag_xref`.

`tbl_object` and `tbl_tag` only have the two columns `id` and `name`.

`tbl_object_tag_xref` matches objects to tags and vice versa, having the columns `id`, `tbl_object_id` and `tbl_tag_id`.

The `tbl_object` and `tbl_tag` tables be already filled with the appropriate data. Only the `tbl_object_tag_xref` table is still empty.

I have a script which parses various data sources and outputs these xrefs in CSV format:

```
"object1","tag1"
"object1","tag2"
"object2","tag2"
...
```

Since the script can fail parsing and produce a few wrong lines, this output is then validated and corrected from humans by hand (the real data here is much more complicated and this can't be automated).

After correction, the data is converted to SQL queries:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_object_tag_xref VALUES (NULL, (SELECT id FROM tbl_object WHERE name = 'object1'), (SELECT id FROM tbl_tag WHERE name = 'tag1'))
INSERT INTO tbl_object_tag_xref VALUES (NULL, (SELECT id FROM tbl_object WHERE name = 'object1'), (SELECT id FROM tbl_tag WHERE name = 'tag2'))
INSERT INTO tbl_object_tag_xref VALUES (NULL, (SELECT id FROM tbl_object WHERE name = 'object2'), (SELECT id FROM tbl_tag WHERE name = 'tag2'))
...
```

Now I want to import this data into the database by sourcing these statements. Of course there is a intrinsic possibility of errors in these statements. How is the best way to debug these errors? Are there tools which can assist me? Should I rethink the whole workflow?

The optimal debugging-workflow for me would look like this (pseudocode):

```
BEGIN;
SOURCE insert_statements.sql;
SUMMARIZE all warnings and errors;
    including information whether already a subquery failed, which one and why
    including information about the respective line numbers and content in the .sql and the .csv files
ASK whether to COMMIT or ROLLBACK;
```

However, `SHOW WARNINGS` and `SHOW ERRORS` does not work, since the failing statement is usually not the last one. `SHOW INNODB STATUS` is a pain in the ass and only shows the last foreign key error, no summary. Since the data may be huge (3000+ lines) scrolling is no option and the output buffer is usually to small to save all the output.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A better approach can be to use a programming/scripting language like Perl. In this case, you can use DBI module to check for each query result and handle the error as needed. You can show the error, save to a file, break or continue execution and so on.

Answer (score 0):

performance_schema = ON   in your .cfg/.ini
run your process then
USE performance_schema;
SELECT * FROM statements_with_errors_or_warnings\G;
will list all the most recent errors or warnings.
Errors will be listed first, then warnings.